# Jenkinsfile shell command not using env variables as expected

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In my Jenkinsfile I want to dynamically find the unity version using a python script like so:

```
environment {
    UNITY_EDITOR = bat(script: "py $WORKSPACE/get_versions.py --unity", returnStdout: true).trim()
    UNITY_BASE = "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/$UNITY_EDITOR/Editor/Unity.exe"
    UNITY_WRAPPER = "UnityBatchWrapper -silent-crashes -no-dialogs -batchmode -quit -unityPath \"$UNITY_BASE\""
}
post {
        always {
            script {
                echo "Returning license"
                licenseReturnStatus = bat ( 
                    script: "$UNITY_WRAPPER -returnlicense",
                    returnStatus: true
                ) == 0
            }
        }
```

From other stackoverflow answers this seems like it should work, but instead my Jenkins job errors out during the post-build step because $UNITY_WRAPPER isn't defined:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: UNITY_WRAPPER for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

I'm thinking the batch step is what's failing, even though Jenkins doesn't complain about it. I've also tried using $env.WORKSPACE and %WORKSPACE% and that doesn't work either.
I'm beginning to think $WORKSPACE doesn't exist til after the environments step...

Comment: Your code in the `post` section is fine and should work, you probably have an issue in the `UNITY_EDITOR = bat(...).trim()` command, which throws an error and therefore `UNITY_BASE` and `UNITY_WRAPPER` parameters are not set and you get the No such property error. verify you don't have ant previous errors in the `environment` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have Python installed since it was an ephemeral GCP builder and I hadn't updated the node label yet.

For anyone reading this that has trouble with bat commands - be sure to put an @ sign in front of your command like "@py ..." or else the command will be echoed in the output. Also trim your output so it doesn't have CRLF in it.